# What's a good alternative to WPF for someone using mono?

Tags: wpf, mono

I'm researching ways to make a music app to randomly generate exercises for the guitar but I'm having a hard time deciding what to go with in terms of a widget toolkit or gui. I keep getting recommended to WPF for this but I want to use Mono which doesn't support WPF. Is there something similar to WPF that supports the Mono Framework? If not, what would be a logical/good alternative and why? I was thinking of using MonoMac for OS X and GTK# for windows, if that says anything.

Note that a good majority of my time is spent on my MacBook Pro and I would prefer to not have to use my old windows desktop as a development environment.

Comment: Mono has a [list of Gui Toolkits](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) it seems.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually knew about that beforehand but I'm having a hard time deciding which one to use.

Comment: Writing your own has been the best solution for me. I wrote my own which provides a subset of WPF features and at the end we are really happy with the framework ( using OpenGL for all drawings ). But some parts are really hard work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xamarin is behind a new cross-platform UI toolkit called XWT  - https://github.com/mono/xwt - (terribly overused name, don't confuse it with the various other XWT toolkits). XWT has various back-end engines, including WPF, GTK# and Cocoa.

I've not used it and suspect it's still pretty immature. But with the Xamarin backing, and some patience and feedback from your side, it looks like a good project to back.

Comment: I've honestly never heard of xwt. I checked it out briefly but there doesn't seem to be a lot of information available. Thanks for the link. I'm going to keep an eye on this.

Comment: Doesn't look too interesting. It's just a UI normalization library so that Mono apps don't look crappy when its ported across platforms. I was hoping for a cross platform WPF, even if it's a small subset. It clearly a superior technology to anything available on any platform. Its scalable vector architecture allows it to be adaptable across platforms.

Comment: @JohnColgrove: I totally agree; I've just read about XWT for the very first time - and more than a year has passed since your post. With the [linked list of GUI toolkits](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) not even mentioning XWT, I can only second your statement about the amount of information available.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind living with a small subset of WPF, you could always use the .NET MicroFramework's WPF library. Don't know the exact limitations, but it's worth a try.

Comment: There is also moonlight, a silverlight port

Comment: Moonlight is no longer supported.  Dead project. It would have been an excellent cross platform story for Mono now that graphic cards are common.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WX.Net](http://wxnet.sourceforge.net/)

WX.Net is a .NET Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) wrapper for wxWidgets. It is composed of two parts:

- wx-c is a C++ library which exposes the wxWidgets API as a collection
  of C# friendly functions.
- WX.Net is a .NET assembly written in C# which parallels the wxWidgets
  class hierarchy.

WX.Net can be used with various implementations of the CLI, including .NET, and Mono.